# Win8 Live Tile vertical image align

Tags: windows-8, vertical-alignment, live-tile

Is there any way to verticaly align an image of a live tile?
The image i'm putting in the tile is to big for the tile and it shows only the center of the image but i would like to show the top.

thnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You can not align image in the live tile. Your only option is to provide live tile with the exact image you would like to show. You can do it by manipulating image locally in the application or background task, or remotely. If you are doing push notifications then server side manipulation is your only choice.

Answer (score 0):

A square tile is 150x150 pixels and a wide tile is 310x150 pixels.  Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh846296.aspx

Just resize the image yourself, and format/crop it how you want (showing the top part).